# another form of $L^p$ norm $\|X\|^p_p=p\int^{\infty}_0\lambda^{p-1}\mathbb{P}(X\geq\lambda)d\lambda$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, lebesgue-measure, stochastic-calculus

let non-negative $X\in L^p(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$ and from norm definition we have

$$\big\| X\big\|^p_p=\int|X|^pd\mathbb{P}$$

I've seen another expression below called property of the $L^p$ norm for $p\in (1,\infty)$

$$\big\|X\big\|^p_p=p\int^{\infty}_0\lambda^{p-1}\mathbb{P}(X\geq\lambda)d\lambda$$

I am not sure if I understand correctly, my gut have some vague understanding of $\mathbb{E}(|X|^p)=\big\|X\big\|^p$, and the second equation somewhat looks like the introductory definition of $\mathbb{E}(|X|^p)$, but isn't it should be $$\int^\infty_0\lambda^p\mathbb{P}(X\geq\lambda)d\lambda$$

Please enlighten me more about this $\big\|X\big\|^p_p=p\int^{\infty}_0\lambda^{p-1}\mathbb{P}(X\geq\lambda)d\lambda$

Comment: This is the layer-cake representation [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation)

Comment: That property can be obtained using Fubini's Theorem

Comment: A small note: the expression should be $p\int_0^\infty \lambda^{p-1} \Pr(|X| \geq \lambda) d \lambda$ since the layer-cake representation only holds for .non-negative random variables You can check that that the presentation in the question doesn't work for $X = -1$, for example.